# Original Hubble diagram units incorrect?

Tags: cosmology, history

Figure 1 from [Hubble 1929](http://apod.nasa.gov/diamond_jubilee/d_1996/hub_1929.html) (original paper with [open access pdf](http://www.pnas.org/content/15/3/168)) has velocity with units of km. Is this just a typo or was there a reason the plot is printed this way?

[image]

Comment: The paper indicates that it should be km/s. Maybe the creator of the graph was not awake when it was made.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is in fact supposed to be in $\mathrm{\frac{km}{s}}$ (KILOMETRES per second).

I think that whoever authored the paper, probably took it as a random shortcut and assumed anyone reading it would either have read the paper and understand it is supposed to be $\mathrm{\frac{km}{s}}$, or just assume it from the fact it says velocity.

Comment: This can also be confirmed by the single cross mark in Figure 1 at the location described by the sentence "The result, 745 km./sec. for a distance of 1.4 x 10[6] parsecs..."